# Magento 2: How to add a custom attribute column to the child products grid view in configurable product in backend

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, admin-panel, custom-attributes, product-grid

I need to add a custom attribute column to the child products grid view in configurable products in backend.

[image]

My initial findings:
 Added 2 custom attributes(similar to the sku) to the products and give corresponding values to that.

By editing the below file:

```
vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/ConfigurablePanel.php

//Added 2 line code to the below function, able to add 2 columns in the grid.

protected function getRows()
{

'oem_sku_container' => $this->getColumn('oem_sku', __('OEM_SKU')),

'internal_sku_container' => $this->getColumn('internal_sku', __('INTERNAL_SKU')),

}
```

[image]

But I didn't get any values of that custom attributes in the column.
There is any way to get the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:
in **Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\ConfigurablePane** page,on

```
protected function getRows()
{
}
```

**remove 'sku_container' => $this->getColumn('sku', __('SKU')),**

and add

```
'oem_sku_container' => $this->getColumn('oem_sku', __('OEMSKU')),
                    'internal_sku_container' => $this->getColumn('internal_sku', __('INTERNALSKU')),
```

**Step:2**

In this page, **Magento\Ui\Component\Form**

on

```
 public function getDataSourceData()
    {
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
        $type_id =   $product->getTypeId();
        if($type_id ==  'configurable'){
            foreach ($data as $key_id => $data_value) {
                if (array_key_exists('configurable-matrix', $data_value)) {

foreach ($data_value['configurable-matrix'] as $configurableMatrixKey => $configurableMatrix) 
{
                        $sam_pid    =   $configurableMatrix['id'];
                        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

                        $productObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
                        ->load($sam_pid);

                        $product_oem_sku = $productObj->getOemSku();
                        $product_internal_sku = $productObj->getInternalSku();

                        $data[$key_id]['configurable-matrix'][$configurableMatrixKey]['oem_sku']      = $product_oem_sku;
                        $data[$key_id]['configurable-matrix'][$configurableMatrixKey]['internal_sku'] = $product_internal_sku;
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
}
```

Comment: How can I rewrite "Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\ConfigurablePanel" to  my module?

Comment: @SameerBhayani you override it by preference because most of the methods in that class are protected. You can't use a Plugin for protected methods. Only modifyData and modifyMeta are public in that class

Comment: thanks :) @phagento

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: create di.xml @ app/code/ABC/XYZ/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="abcXyzConfigurablePanel" xsi:type="string">ABC\XYZ\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbcXyzAttribute</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Step:2 Create Data Provider Class AbcXyzAttribute.php**
app/code/ABC/XYZ/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/AbcXyzAttribute.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace ABC\XYZ\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\ConfigurablePanel;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form;

/**
 * Data provider for Configurable panel.
 */
class AbcXyzAttribute extends AbstractModifier
{

    /**
     * @var LocatorInterface
     */
    private $locator;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepository
     */
    protected $_productRepository;

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param ProductRepository $productRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        
        $productId = $this->locator->getProduct()->getId();
        
        if (isset($data[$productId][ConfigurablePanel::CONFIGURABLE_MATRIX])) {
            foreach ($data[$productId][ConfigurablePanel::CONFIGURABLE_MATRIX] as $key => $productArray) {
                $product =  $this->_productRepository->get($productArray[ProductInterface::SKU]);
                $abcXyz = $product->getData('abc_xyz');
                $data[$productId][ConfigurablePanel::CONFIGURABLE_MATRIX][$key]['abc_xyz'] = $abcXyz;
            }
        }
       
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Composes configuration for "abc_xyz_container" component.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getAbcXyzContainerConfig(): array
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Form\Element\Input::NAME,
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/text',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/dynamic-rows/cells/text',
                        'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Text::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => 'abc_xyz',
                        'label' => __('ABC XYZ'),
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        
        $meta[ConfigurablePanel::GROUP_CONFIGURABLE]['children']
        [ConfigurablePanel::CONFIGURABLE_MATRIX]['children']
        ['record']['children']['abc_xyz_container'] = $this->getAbcXyzContainerConfig();
        return $meta;
    }
}
```