# Configurable Products Current Variations Grid Custom Attribute

Tags: magento2

When creating a configurable product does anyone know of a way to add a custom product attributes to the variations grid so you don't have to then go into to each simple product and enter it in seperately. Screenshot of the area I mean below.

I've seen this [Magento 2: How to add a custom attribute column to the child products grid view in configurable product in backend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171131/magento-2-how-to-add-a-custom-attribute-column-to-the-child-products-grid-view) however it no longer seems to work.

[image: Configurable Products Grid]